# Magento getUrl not working with catalog/category object?

Tags: php, parsing, magento, e-commerce, geturl

I've been able to instantiate a category object to retrieve its name, but when I use the `getUrl` method it isn't returning a URL to the category listing page, or anything at all

```
<?php
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3);
foreach ($children as $category):
            echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>';
        endforeach;
?>
```

The code above results in HTML output of

```
<li><a href="">name of sub-cat</a></li>`
```

Does anyone know how I can get the URL for a category page from a  `catalog/category` object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3);
```

with

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: This one did it! Thanks so much Gordon!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is [`getCategories()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category.html#getCategories) normally returns a `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection` rather than a collection of categories. Instead, you can do this:

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3, 0, false, true);
```

The fourth parameter is `$asCollection`, passing a `true` means you are returned a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection` which you were probably expecting. The rest should work now.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However I was looking to only display the first level children categories, which the two answers below took care of. Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: For the sake of future readers you can control the depth of levels with the second parameter; instead of `0` put `1` for just the first level, `2` for first and second, etc. You are right that Gordon's answer does the same thing and is neater too.

Comment: Hi Clockworkgeek,

Can you tell me how to add an if statement to say: if the catoegories have children, link to child category, if not, link normal category link. (For mobile site)

Answer (score 3):

You may load every category within the foreach loop and then get the category URL.

```
<?php
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3);
foreach ($children as $category): 
        $categoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getEntityId())->getUrl();
        echo '<li><a href="' . $categoryUrl . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>';
endforeach;
?>
```

This might work fine for less number of categories. However, this might take more time if you have large number of categories.